# For loop, switch boolean

Tags: java, for-loop, boolean

I am trying to make a for loop and switch in every loop the boolean.
In the first place I made an array of `100` lockers, in which everyone are closed.
 Then, in the first loop, I want to open all of the lockers, then change the state of every second locker (2,4,6...etc.) and so on, till at the end, it in only changes the state of the `100th` locker.

So, if its false(locked) it should change to true and if its true(open) the other way around. The problem is, I am not entirely sure how to change the state, I am looking forward for your help.

Please suggest any solution

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[] lockers = new boolean[101];
    for (int i = 1; i < lockers.length; i++) {
        lockers[i] = false; 
        }
    for (int i = 1; i < lockers.length; i++) {
        lockers[i+i] = lockers[i+i] == true ? false : true;
        if(lockers[i] == true)
            System.out.print("o"); //open
        if(lockers[i] == false) {
            System.out.print("c"); //closed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this _java_ ?

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean[] lockers = new boolean[100]; // All are false
boolean be = false;
for (int i = 0; i < lockers.length; i++) {
    be = !be;
    lockers[i] = be;
    if (lockers[i]) {// Or if (be)
        System.out.print("o"); // open
    } else {
        System.out.print("c"); // closed
    }
}
System.out.println(); // Write the line out on the console.

Instead:      Use:
c == true     c
c == false    !c         (Not operator !)
```

Then there are some array index troubles: `new boolean[100]` delivers 100 booleans set to false, with indices 0 .. 99.

Comment: Ok, alright, cheers! Now I am trying to change the state of every third locker, so 3rd,6th,9th, 12th... 99th. Afterwards every 4th,8th,12th,16th, then every 5th,10th,15th... until I reach the last loop where the 100 lockers changes the state. But I thought it would do that already, since the lockers.length is 100 and i adds 1 every loop.

Comment: `i % 3 == 0` (modulo) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[] lockers = new boolean[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < lockers.length; i++) {
        lockers[i] = false; 
        }
    for (int i = 1; i % 2 == 0 && i < lockers.length; i++) {
        lockers[i] = true;
    }
}
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[] lockers = new boolean[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < lockers.length; i++) {
        lockers[i] = false; 
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < lockers.length; i=i+2) {
        lockers[i] = true;
    }
}
```

or when you just want to invert the boolean of the even fields

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[] lockers = new boolean[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < lockers.length; i++) {
        lockers[i] = false; 
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < lockers.length; i=i+2) {
        lockers[i] = !lockers[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: `lockers[i] == !lockers[i]` what are you comparing here? and in the other examples, too. do you mean `=` instead of `==`?

Comment: yeah... sorry... changed that